# Dragging and Dropping a text file onto Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I am developing a Desktop Application in which I need to drag and drop a text file onto a JAVA applet and that applet should automatically be able to detect the absolute path of the file and should be able to perform some operations. (Like in my case upload on a server)

I am having problem in accepting the file on that applet which is a JTextArea.

Any help along with code and explanation will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Following is a code for droping a file and showing its path. But the problem is that the applet accepts file only from File explorer not directly from desktop or any other window.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main extends JFrame implements DropTargetListener {
  DropTarget dt;
  JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
  public Main() {
    super("Drop Test");
    setSize(300, 300 );
    getContentPane()
        .add(new JLabel("Drop something here:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    ta.setBackground(Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dt = new DropTarget(ta, this);
    setVisible(true);
  }

 public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
   // System.out.println("Drag Enter");
  }

  public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
    //System.out.println("Drag Exit");
  }

  public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
    //System.out.println("Drag Over");
  }

  public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
    System.out.println("Drop Action Changed");
  }

  public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    try {
        System.out.println("in drop");
      Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();

      DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
      System.out.println(flavors.length);
      for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
        if (flavors[i].isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
            System.out.println("In if");
          dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
          List list = (List) tr.getTransferData(flavors[i]);
          for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            ta.append(list.get(j) + "\n");
          }
          dtde.dropComplete(true);
          return;
        } else if (flavors[i].isFlavorSerializedObjectType()) {
          dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
          Object o = tr.getTransferData(flavors[i]);
          ta.append("Object: " + o.getClass());
          dtde.dropComplete(true);
          return;
        } else if (flavors[i].isRepresentationClassInputStream()) {
          dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
          ta.read(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) tr.getTransferData(flavors[i])),
              "from system clipboard");
          dtde.dropComplete(true);
          return;
        }
      }
      dtde.rejectDrop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Is the applet signed? Does it have permission to read from the client machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the transferHandler to the textArea then (as posted above)...

```
private JtextArea ta;
public AppletTest() throws HeadlessException {
    super();
    TransferHandler tf = new TransferHandler(){
        //code as above
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport arg0) {

            for (DataFlavor df:  arg0.getDataFlavors() ){
                if (df.isFlavorJavaFileListType() ){
                     return true;
                }
            }
            //we only accept files
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport arg0) {
            try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<File> oList = (List<File>) arg0.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                 //check that you don't have multiple files selected
                if (oList.size() == 1){
                    File myFile = oList.get(0);
                    ta.setText(myFile.toString() );
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.importData(arg0);
        }
    };

    ta = new JTextArea();
    this.add(ta);   
    ta.setTransferHandler(tf);

}
```

i hope that helped...

as requested: the whole data context:

```
public class AppletTest extends JApplet{

    private JTextArea ta;

    public AppletTest() throws HeadlessException {
        //as seen above
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the class structure. If you can write that too it would be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

you must implement your own Transferhandler in that applet (or your TextArea, in both cases you can set your own transfer handler):

NOTE: this is mostly 1:1 taken from the java drag&drop tutorials

```
public AppletTest() throws HeadlessException {
    super();
    TransferHandler tf = new TransferHandler(){
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport arg0) {

            for (DataFlavor df:  arg0.getDataFlavors() ){
                if (df.isFlavorJavaFileListType() ){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            //we only accept files
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport arg0) {
            try {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<File> oList = (List<File>) arg0.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                for(File o: oList){
                    System.out.println("file:"+o);                      
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.importData(arg0);
        }

    };
    this.setTransferHandler(tf);
}
```

once you have the files, the rest should be easy...

Comment: is there a need to override the drop method from dropTargetListener interface for that particular applet?

Comment: Hello Suhrid Singh, there is no need to implement further methos for your purpose (if you only want to retrive the files).

Comment: hey Martin still not able to fulfill the requirement. Could you please pass on a working code in file I am able to drop a text file from desktop on a java applet(JTextArea) and file name is printed on the console. Thnks in Advance :)

Comment: hey Martin the program worked but a little glitch in it. I am able to drag file only from a file explorer of some editor (the window when we open file from File Tab). Else I am not able to drag some file from desktop or some other location.

Comment: ohm, uh, i'm a little curious - i tested that code with dnd from desktop files... i think i can't help you with THAT issue, but please fell free to ask further questions!

Comment: it's done. Don't know why but Eclipse was the problem. It worked when I complied and executed it from cmd prompt :)

Comment: Hooray, i'm glad it worked for you - good luck with your further implementations!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. U have been a great help :)